# random Decimal in python

Tags: python, random, decimal

How do I get a random [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects) instance? It appears that the random module only returns floats which are a pita to convert to Decimals.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What's "a random decimal"? Decimals have arbitrary precision, so generating a number with as much randomness as you can hold in a Decimal would take the entire memory of your machine to store.

You have to know how many decimal digits of precision you want in your random number, at which point it's easy to just grab an random integer and divide it. For example if you want two digits above the point and two digits in the fraction (see [randrange here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange)):

```
decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(10000))/100
```

Comment: So, you're suggesting that the fact that there is a finite length means that the results are not random?

Answer (score 16):

From the [standard library reference](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/library/decimal.html) :

To create a Decimal from a float, first convert it to a string. This serves as an explicit reminder of the details of the conversion (including representation error).

```
>>> import random, decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(str(random.random()))
Decimal('0.467474014342')
```

Is this what you mean? It doesn't seem like a pita to me. You can scale it into whatever range and precision you want.

Answer (score 9):

If you know how many digits you want after and before the comma, you can use:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> import random
>>> def gen_random_decimal(i,d):
...  return decimal.Decimal('%d.%d' % (random.randint(0,i),random.randint(0,d)))

...
>>> gen_random_decimal(9999,999999) #4 digits before, 6 after
Decimal('4262.786648')
>>> gen_random_decimal(9999,999999)
Decimal('8623.79391')
>>> gen_random_decimal(9999,999999)
Decimal('7706.492775')
>>> gen_random_decimal(99999999999,999999999999) #11 digits before, 12 after
Decimal('35018421976.794013996282')
>>>
```

Comment: If it matters here: the fractional part of such a number would not be uniformly random, due to removal of leading zeroes. You can't get '2.0something' out of it.

Comment: I considered this too, but it would be neater to take (4, 6) as the arguments instead of (9999, 999999) and then just use 10**4 - 1, 10**6 - 1 in the function body.

Comment: I agree with both comments :-)

Comment: Or something like "%d.%0*d" % ( random.randint(0,10**ni-1), nd, random.randint(0,10**nd-1) ); assuming nd and ni are the number of digits requested

Comment: @S.Lott: Ah, that takes care of the leading zeros. Nice one.

Comment: If you're expecting true randomness, you wouldn't be using python anyway, thanks for the answer showing how to use python to get as much pseudo-randomness as we can expect in this particular case

Answer (score 2):

The random module has more to offer than "only returning floats", but anyway:

```
from random import random
from decimal import Decimal
randdecimal = lambda: Decimal("%f" % random.random())
```

Or did I miss something obvious in your question ?

Answer (score 2):

```
decimal.Decimal(random.random() * MAX_VAL).quantize(decimal.Decimal('.01'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to make a random decimal.

```
import random
round(random.randint(1, 1000) * random.random(), 2)
```

On this example,

- **random.randint()** generates random integer in specified range (inclusively),
- **random.random()** generates random floating point number in the range (0.0, 1.0)
- Finally, **round()** function will round the multiplication result of the abovementioned values multiplication (something long like 254.71921934351644) to the specified number after the decimal point (in our case we'd get 254.71)

Comment: The OP wants a `decimal.Decimal` instance. Your code creates a `float`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
y = eval(input("Enter the value of y for the range of random number : "))
x = round(y*random.random(),2)  #only for 2 round off 
print(x)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.