# How to generate random Decimal128, Decimal256 numbers with Python

Tags: python, random, decimal, clickhouse

I am making a test for ClickHouse [database](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/decimal/) for verifying Decimal data types.
According to documentation:

**Decimal Parameters:**

P - precision. Valid range: [1 : 76]. Determines how many decimal digits number can have (including fraction).
S - scale. Valid range: [0 : P]. Determines how many decimal digits fraction can have.
Depending on P parameter value Decimal(P, S) is a synonym for:

- P from [1 : 9] - for Decimal32(S)
- P from [10 : 18] - for Decimal64(S)
- P from [19 : 38] - for Decimal128(S)
- P from [39 : 76] - for Decimal256(S)

I am trying to generate random numbers for all of these data types.
I've found a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439115/random-decimal-in-python) already and this is how I used it:

**Decimal32:**

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(random.randint(-2147483648, 2147483647))/1000
Decimal('-47484.47')
```

**Decimal64:**

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(random.randint(-9223372036854775808, 9223372036854775807))/100000000000
Decimal('-62028733.96730274309')
```

These two give me the expected result.
But, my function for **Decimal128** already is too long and produces wrong result:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(random.randint(-170141183460469231731687303715884105728, 170141183460469231731687303715884105727))/1000000000000000000000
Decimal('149971182339396169.8957534906')
```

**Question:**

How can I generate random **Decimal128** and **Decimal256**?

Please suggest what I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you face, is that the precisison is not set high enough to record all the digits in your division. The simplest way to fix it, is to increase the precision (at the expense of the division and all other operations taking longer to execute. The default precision is set to 28, that is 28 correct fractional digits. This is enough for **Decimal64**, but too few for **Decimal128** and **Decimal256**

To update the precision you write:

```
decimal.getcontext().prec = 38 # Maximum number of fractional digits in Decimal128
```

After this your code should work. Of course, for **Decimal256**, the precision needs to be set to 76.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll wait if there are maybe some alternative ways. If nobody else answers, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: There are other ways, such as generate the data in string format and read that directly into a `Decimal` object, with the string as argument. But, that is most likely more cumbersome. You can reset the precision to 28, after you are done generating your data also, if you think you need to.